# Read from arg / parameter in tasm

Tags: assembly, tasm

i have
`color dw ?`

and

```
parm:
mov ah, 62h
int 21h 
mov es, bx  
mov bx, 80h 

mov cl, [es:bx] 
cmp cl, 2 
ret 

mov bx, 82h 
xor ax, ax
xor dx, dx

mov dl, [es:bx]
sub dl, '0'     
mov [col], dl
inc bx
```

I want read value of parameter, but there are error: operand types do not match. Why this not work?

Comment: Proofread your code carefully. You have `mov dl,` with no second argument.

Comment: sorry, there is mov dl, [es:bx];

Comment: prog.asm(214), it is line: mov [col], dl
Operand types do not match

Comment: How is `col` defined? If you are moving from `dl`, then the assembler expects a byte data type. So it must be defined as a `db` or you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

From **"i have color dw ?"** I get that the variable is word sized.
Since you cleared the DX register beforehand you should change `mov [col], dl` into `mov [color],dx` to store the result.

A second problem is that you compare the length of the commandline but fail to jump if there's no argument. You can replace the `ret` by a `jb` to a location that exits the application.

```
mov cl, [es:bx] 
cmp cl, 2
jb NoArg
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an instruction such as the following in x86 assembly:

```
mov [col], dl
```

The `dl` register is 8 bits, and so this is *necessarily* an 8-bit data operation. If `col` is *not* defined as an 8 bit value, you will get an operand type error. `col` needs to be defined as an 8-bit value, for example:

```
col db ?
```

Since in your code you've cleared the high byte of `dx` with `xor dx, dx` before loading `dl`, you could move a word:

```
mov [col], dx
```

Here, the assembler will assume that the data type is *necessarily* 16 bits, so `col` must be defined as a word, such as:

```
col dw ?
```